# Do we need to clean the project each time when I develop?

Tags: java, gradle, build, ant

I have a huge java web-project. Recently I have migrated to **gradle** build from ant build.

**Is it necessary to do 'clean' task each time I build ?**
*Or*
**What is the actual purpose of 'clean' task ?**

(*I know that 'clean' will clean the output directory. But I think always the files will get replaced each time I compile.* Then why do we need to spend time to clean again)

*There is one reason to clean* (as I know) :
If you remove a file and build without cleaning it, the old file will remain in the output folder until you clean it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to 'clean' every time you build. If I recall gradle should only rebuild files that you've modified and all their dependents. See [Why run 'gradle clean'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028748/why-run-gradle-clean) for the second part of your question.