# Spring boot application local build passes, but fails in Jenkins due to Tests

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, spring-boot

When executing gradle build command in local system for xxxx-app, the build is successful. But When I execute the build through Jenkins job, the build gets fails when executing the Spring boot application Tests as shown below.

```
:xxxx-app:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:xxxx-app:testClasses
:xxxx-app:test

com.xxxx.yyyy.XXXXApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

1 test completed, 1 failed
:xxxx-app:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I believe this is something to do with test dependencies in build.gradle, But not sure the same is getting successful in local system. I am using below dependency,

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

Can some one help on this issue due to this I could not proceed further in Jenkins job?

Comment: stack trace from the test says ?

Comment: and btw what is the test doing ? maybe it's trying to component test the app if it starts? if so maybe is checking on 'localhost' which may be different if runs on jvm?.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, it was an issue with test failures in old Jenkins builds. 
 You will need to add `gradle clean` before `gradle test`.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030305/2884309) for explanation when do we need to do `gradle clean`.