# How to sync gradle in React Native (android)?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I tried `./gradlew build` but that didn't work, because it doessnt see the changes made in gradle file. The only thing that works for me is restarting and invalidating cache, but there must be a better way to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try running `./gradlew clean` before building.

Answer (score 0):

change directory to **/{your project}/android**  then run below commands

1. `./gradlew clean`
2. `./gradlew build`

Note :-
you will get error : `./gradlew: No such file or directory`
if you are trying gradlew commands outside android folder.

also check this : [Why run 'gradle clean build' instead of 'gradle build'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028748/why-run-gradle-clean-build-instead-of-gradle-build)